# How to set a default -vm option for maven build in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The `Run As > Maven build...` command in `eclipse` has a `VM Arguments` tab.

How can I force eclipse to always insert a default vmarg there during compilation? Eg `-Xmx1g`? Is that possible at all?

Sidenote: I don't want to give eclipse itself the -Xmx vmarg (like eclipse.ini). But the mvn compilation process!

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11556760/829571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set that in the JRE VM args option in the IDE run configuration.

[image]

Quick  thing , this can be set at a plugin level as well , https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-with-memory-enhancements.html which will then be used during run.

Comment: Adding this vmarg on mavne compiler pom level is even nicer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process
Right Click on Project > Run As > Run Configuration.

In the next window, select Maven Build in left and add new Configuration. In the same window, under the JRE tab, you can add on your default VM arguments.