# Signing jar created with onejar-maven-plugin throwing stackoverflow exception

Tags: stack-overflow, jarsigner, onejar

I have a jar which is created using `onejar-maven-plugin`, which is meant to listen to jms messages from tibco and process accordingly. It works fine but when I sign this jar using `jarsigner` and try to run it, it throws the exception below:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.StackOverflowError (Caused by java.lang.StackOverflowError)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:538)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.adobe.jobcloud.envoy.client.PushToPrereleaseWorker.main(PushToPrereleaseWorker.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.OneJarFile.getJarEntry(OneJarFile.java:43)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.maybeInstantiateVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.OneJarFile.getJarEntry(OneJarFile.java:50)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.maybeInstantiateVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.OneJarFile.getJarEntry(OneJarFile.java:50)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
```

Also if I use `maven-jarsigner-plugin` to sign it, the result is exactly same. I'm clueless and stuck up with this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue.  Any luck on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the -Xss JVM option? To 4096k at first, then lower it until it fails again.
Working with ciphers generally maybe need more than default stack size.
For the maven jarsigner plugin you can edit .mavenrc file in your linux home directory and add these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-i586 #(or another)
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/lib/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xss4096k -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx384m"
```

I don't know how to do this under windows, but there must be similar solution ([here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819853/setting-java-heap-space-under-maven-2-on-windows))