# How to specify java vm in VM arguments

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a maven project I want to run it using 64 bit jvm in the project run configuration under VM arguments I set the following

```
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin
```

It says Unrecognized option -vm

Can anyone tell me how to set jvm from VM arguments?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use

Comment: I changed my JAVA_HOME variable in Enviromant variables but I still get the error

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1945600KB object heap

Comment: You are trying to reserve 2GB of heap to run maven (by using `-Xmx2g` or something similar). You probably don't want that... See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819853/setting-java-heap-space-under-maven-2-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

As you highlighted in one of your comments, after changing `JAVA_HOME` to another VM, you are getting a error message saying:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for 1945600KB object heap

The problem here is that some configuration is setting the `-Xms` argument to something around `2G` or `2048M`. Look into your run configuration and remove that setting. If you are experiencing `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820738/4464702).

Comment: I removed -Xms from my run configuration and set JAVA_HOME to 64bit jvm I get this error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: How much RAM do you have installed on your machine?

Comment: I have 4GB Ram using 64bit OS

Comment: I also tried this answer setting MAVEN_OPTS but it didn't work for me

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work for me"? I am not here to guess what is wrong with your setup. Tell me about error messages.